# Como descobrir quantos slots/bancos de memória estão sendo utilizados em VB

Tags: visual-basic-6, vbs

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto em Visual Basic e gostaria de saber como posso ler a quantidade de slots/bancos de memória RAM há em uso no computador, também o valor de memória RAM instalada em cada slot/banco em uso, e o total de memória RAM.

Comment: O que é slot de memória?

Comment: Tipo quero saber quantos pentes de memoria o meu computador tem, exemplo: 2 pente de 4 GB, totalizando 8 GB

Answer (score 4):

---

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

Bem vindo ao **SO/pt**

Você pode obter as informações usando o **[`WMI`](https://www.infonova.com.br/artigo/poderosa-ferramenta-chamada-wmic/)** no seu **`vbs`**:

---

```VBS
strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_PhysicalMemory",,48)
Total_size = 0 
For Each objItem in colItems
    size = FormatNumber(objItem.Capacity/1024^3, 0)
    Wscript.Echo "Slot: " + objItem.BankLabel + vbNewLine + "Capacidade: " & size & "GB" & vbNewLine +  "Obs.: " + objItem.Tag
    Total_size= (Total_size + size)
Next
Wscript.Echo "Total de Ram: " & Total_size & "GB"
```

---

> Ou com um contador de Slots em uso:

---

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

```VBS
strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_PhysicalMemory",,48)
Total_Size = 0 
Total_Slot = 0
For Each objItem in colItems
    Size = FormatNumber(objItem.Capacity/1024^3, 0)
    If Size <> 0 Then
    Wscript.Echo "Slot: " + objItem.BankLabel + vbNewLine + "Capacidade: " & Size & "GB" & vbNewLine +  "Obs.: " + objItem.Tag
    Total_Size= (Total_Size + Size)
    Total_Slot= Total_Slot + 1
    End If
Next
Wscript.Echo "Slots em uso: " & Total_Slot & vbNewLine & "Total de Ram: " & Total_size & "GB"
```

---

---